# S3 to Redshift using COPY: Cannot COPY into nonexistent table

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm new to Redshift & S3.

I try to save data to S3 and retrieve it.
While saving to S3 works, retrieving returns error:

`saving`

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT 5 as field')
TO 's3://my_bucket/test_001/example_1'
-- identification --
REGION 'us-east-1'
HEADER
ALLOWOVERWRITE
CSV
```

--> worked

---

`retrieving`

```
COPY example_1  FROM 's3://my_bucket/test_001/' 
-- same identification as above -- 
CSV
```

--> returns error `INTERNAL_ERROR :: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Cannot COPY into nonexistent table example_1`

What am I doing wrong? AFAIK I followed this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table you are COPYing into needs to exists before the COPY command is run - in your case the table "example_1".  This can be done in a number of ways but direct way is with CREATE TABLE command. Since you just want to store a single column with what I assume is an integer value just run

```
CREATE TABLE example_1 (A INT);
```

before you run the COPY command.