# How do I fix the S3 load error "Cannot COPY into nonexistent table"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to load the data from S3 into redshift. However I am facing this issue of "Cannot COPY into nonexistent table dataset".
My COPY command syntax is as follows:

> COPY dataset
> FROM 's3://stormbreakerv1/ASIN LIST.csv'
> iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::417556863011:role/DGHS3C-RS-UNLOAD-COPY,arn:aws:iam::541453733646:role/RoleChainHS3C'
> format AS csv
> DELIMITER ','
> DATEFORMAT 'auto'
> IGNOREHEADER 1 maxerror 10
> emptyasnull blanksasnull TRUNCATECOLUMNS NULL AS 'null' ACCEPTINVCHARS;

Comment: Error message is clear- is it your contention that table does exist?

Comment: The temp table had to be created before the copy command, now it is working.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Looks like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66746196/s3-to-redshift-using-copy-cannot-copy-into-nonexistent-table
in the same question